# ExecuteReader requires an open connection. The connection's current state is closed

Tags: vb.net

I am getting the error:

> ExecuteReader requires an open connection. The connection's current state is closed.

The code is:

```
 Public Shared Sub FillInvoiceGrid(datagrid As DataGridView)
        Dim connection As OleDbConnection = AutoBeautyCareDB.GetConnection
        Dim selectStatement As String = "SELECT INV_NO,INV_DATE,(C_NAME+' '+C_SURNAME) AS NAME,TOTAL " &
                                        "FROM Invoice INNER JOIN Customer ON Invoice.[CUST#] = Customer.[CUST#]"
        Dim selectCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(selectStatement, connection)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(behavior:=CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Dim tb As New DataTable
            tb.Columns.Add("InvoiceNo")
            tb.Columns.Add("InvDate")
            tb.Columns.Add("Customer")
            tb.Columns.Add("Total")
            Do While reader.Read
                tb.Rows.Add(reader("INV_NO"), reader("INV_DATE"), reader("NAME"), reader("TOTAL"))
            Loop
            datagrid.DataSource = tb

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex

        Finally
            connection.Close()

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use the table.Load(reader) method to create and fill the table?

Comment: I guess we need to see `GetConnection`. `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` closes the connection when the reader is closed. Since you are not closing the reader I doubt if this is doing anything.

Comment: Get rid of your `Catch` block. It is worse than useless. You are only required to have one of `Catch` and `Finally` so, if you have a `Finally` block, there's no point having a `Catch` block that does nothing but rethrow. I say that yours is worse than useless because it actually truncates the stack trace. You should pretty much never use `Throw ex` for that reason, but rather just use `throw`.

Comment: As for the issue, have you actually debugged your code? Presumably not. Simply reading the code is not enough. Yes, it looks like the connection is open but, if it was, you would not be getting that error message. Debug the code and actually watch it in action. If you don't know how to debug, start learning [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Need more information: What is that 'AutoBeautyCareDB' (also shared and not nothing?) and where the error is thrown?

Comment: Thank you.. I have solved the issue